# How to get the set of warning checks currently enabled in the perl module?

Tags: perl

In the [perllexwarn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllexwarn.html) are defined all warnings what is possible to set.

But here is nothing about, how to print out what warnings i have currently enabled.

E.g.:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print warnings::enabled->pretty_print(); #fictional...
```

How is it possible?

example:

```
use strict;
use 5.012;
use warnings;

my $aaa;
say "$aaa";

say warnings::enabled("uninitialized") ? "yes" : "no";
```

The above will output:

```
Use of uninitialized value $aaa in string at y line 6.

no
```

so, the "uninitialized" warning category is "set", because its prints a warning, but the `warnings::enabled("uninitialized")` not returns `true`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reading [perllexwarn](http://p3rl.org/perllexwarn)

> ... functions that are useful for module authors. These are used when you
>   want to report a module-specific warning to a calling module has
>   enabled warnings via the "warnings" pragma.

If I understand it correctly, it means the functions (`enabled`, `warnif`) only work for module-specific warnings, not for the standard categories. (There is probably a missing "that" before "has" in the documentation.)

**Update:** It seems standard categories work as well, but only in a module:

```
package MY;
use warnings::register;
sub S {
    my $x;
    print $x, "\t";
    print warnings::enabled("uninitialized"),"\n";
}

package main;
use warnings;
MY::S();
no warnings;
MY::S();
```

Comment: Right, it is meant to be used by module authors, to determine if the code that is using the module has turned on warnings. If you are not a module author, and put "use warnings" in your script, then you already know they are on, there is no facility to check them.

Comment: @Dondi Michael Stroma, so `use warnings` is the same as `use warnings qw(all)`? And when someone using `use uni::perl` what warning will be set and what no? (you can ofc read the source code to check) but anyway - here must be some way to check what bits are turned on. E.g. somewhat with the ${^WARNING_BITS} or soo...

Comment: It also depends on how you call your script. `perl -le 'use warnings; print $^W, warnings::enabled("uninitialized");'` will return `00` but with `-w` it will return `11`.

Comment: Except that the synopsis for `warnings` shows `warnings::enabled("void")` as one of the examples, and that _is_ one of the standard categories.